# HTML/CSS: Image link partially covered by another image link is not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have two  tags containing  tags. They are positioned relatively, and one has a negative z-index, to appear behind the other. They are offset though, so that there is plenty of visible area on the lower link.
The lower link is not clickable and does not register CSS hovers. Most of what I can find online suggests to set the covering element to "pointer-events: none", however my covering element is also a link, so I still want it to be clickable.

EDIT: jsfiddle demonstrating problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cfbxz7pb/

```html
<div style="position: relative">

<a href="http://www.google.com" style="position: relative">
  <img style="width: 150px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="position: relative; left:-60px; z-index: -5">
  <img style="width: 150px; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(80deg)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" style="position: relative; left:-120px">
  <img style="width: 150px; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(120deg)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS and maybe a fiddle? Do you really need a negative `z-index`?

Comment: Post a working code snippet reproducing the issue

Comment: how is the smaller div even visible if it's underneath? and if it's above, it should be clickable.

Comment: Alright here's a fiddle reproducing the issue. Middle circle is not clickable: https://jsfiddle.net/cfbxz7pb/

Comment: Remove the negative `z-index` and give the link that's on top a positive `z-index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second link/circle has z-index of -5 which will always put it under anything else (unless you use an even lower z-index next to it). Make the second link/circle z-index at least 0, but defnitely higher than the other two circles; I used z-index: 2 in this case.

I recommend this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="position: relative; left:-60px; z-index: 2">
```

And add css defining all the a hrefs as display: inline-block like this:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Another way to do this is to create three divs and make them border-radius: 100%, that way their overlaps are actually circles, not the squares created by the a href and the png image inside.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="position: relative">

<a href="http://www.google.com" style="position: relative;  z-index: 77;">
  <img style="width: 150px; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="position: relative; left:-60px; z-index: 0">
  <img style="width: 150px; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(80deg)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" style="position: relative; left:-120px;   z-index: 0">
  <img style="width: 150px; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(120deg);" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg">
</a>

</div>
```